# How to set scroll position of UITableView on view's load?

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I have a UITableView where I want to hide the header of the first row, unless the user scrolls up ward, then it can be present.

My current approach is the following:

```
Table.ContentInset = new UIEdgeInsets(-30, 0, 0, 0);
Table.ScrolledToTop += (sender, e) => {
        Table.ContentInset = new UIEdgeInsets(0, 0, 0, 0);

};
```

But this does not work as expected. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method:

```
tableView.ScrollToRow (Foundation.NSIndexPath.FromItemSection (0, 0), UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, false);
```

This is the complete code:

```
tableView = new UITableView (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
            this.View.AddSubview (tableView);

            UILabel header = new UILabel (new CGRect (0, 0, tableView.Frame.Width, 50)){BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue};
            header.Text = "I'm header";
            header.TextColor = UIColor.White;
            header.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
            tableView.TableHeaderView = header;

            TableViewSource mySource = new TableViewSource ();
            tableView.Source = mySource;
            tableView.ReloadData ();

            tableView.ScrollToRow (Foundation.NSIndexPath.FromItemSection (0, 0), UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, false);
```

Hope it can help you.